# How to save product in cookie ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, cookies

How to make the product be added to cookies when clicked on "ADD TO CART", and again removed when clicked? ASP.NET

```
@{ foreach (var product in Model)
{
    <div class="col pb-20 pt-10">
        <div class="ee-product">
            <div class="image">
                <a href="/Electronics/SingleProduct" class="img">
                    <img src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Admin", new { productId = product.Id })" width="120" height="300" />
                </a>

                <a href="" class="add-to-cart">
                    <i class="ti-shopping-cart"></i><span>ADD TO CART</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi Seropchik. Welcome to stackoverflow. Just as an input on how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.
Although I feel like somebody with knowledge about asp.net could help you out, you could probably include a bit more information about what your code actually does and what not. Also try to be polite and ask like it. After all somebody is taking her/his free time to write an answer to help you.

Comment: You can use Javascript to set the cookie. Please see https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp.